# Grunt-cli and Grunt - Same app, two versions?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

### Achtung!

The accepted answer answered my question at the time, but is now outdated. Back then grunt-cli used grunt, but with another branch. 
The not-accepted answers will tell you how it is today.

### Question

What is the relations and differences between grunt-cli and grunt?
It seems to be the same thing, but different versions.

### Grunt

https://npmjs.org/package/grunt

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt

### Grunt-cli

https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-cli

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/devel/docs/getting_started.md

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're correct, the two projects exist because of different versions of grunt.

`grunt-cli` is used for grunt version 0.4 (and has an [explicit dependency on 0.4](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-cli/blob/master/package.json#L28)), which as of this writing is  in alpha development. grunt-0.4 splits the command line interface (grunt-cli) from the API libraries.

The ["Getting Started"](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/devel/docs/getting_started.md) documentation you found is in the [`devel` branch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/tree/devel) of the grunt repository, which will be the 0.4 release.

If you're using grunt 0.3.x, then you don't need to install `grunt-cli`.

Comment: It seems like the `0.4` dependency has since been removed from `grunt-cli` project so my answer above is already be out-of-date.

Answer (score 9):

As far as I know, grunt-cli is simply a tool to access Grunt from command line anywhere in the system, but it doesn't include Grunt itself. In other words, Grunt-CLI only looks for locally installed Grunt files somewhere in the filesystem, but it doesn't have the functionality of the regular Grunt.

Comment: so do we need to install both grunt-cli and grunt?? Or just "npm install grunt --save-dev" is enough for a angularjs project??

Answer (score 7):

From: http://gruntjs.com/getting-started

> Install grunt-cli just will put the grunt command in your system path, allowing it to be run from any directory.

Even more:

> ...Installing grunt-cli does not install the Grunt task runner! The job of the Grunt CLI is simple: run the version of Grunt which has been installed next to a Gruntfile. This allows multiple versions of Grunt to be installed on the same machine simultaneously.