# Why does grunt allow global installations?

Tags: gruntjs

I've installed both the grunt-cli and grunt globally using the -g option.

However when I try and run grunt I get this error:

```
grunt --gruntfile /Users/a/root/config/Gruntfile.js
grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.13)

Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

If you're seeing this message, either a Gruntfile wasn't found or grunt
hasn't been installed locally to your project. For more information about
installing and configuring grunt, please see the Getting Started guide:

http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
```

This is confusing as it seems to say that you are suppose to do a local install.

It seems contradictory actually.  I clearly have a grunt file in place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grunt-cli and Grunt - Same app, two versions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704917/grunt-cli-and-grunt-same-app-two-versions)

Answer (score 0):

Grunt-cli is installed globally so that the `grunt` command is available to be run from any location on your system. Without the global installation, you would need to rely on somewhat abstract methods of running local grunt installs (`npm run-script` and friends), which are clunky for this use.

The [entire point of the global install is *only* to load and run a local `Gruntfile.js` using the locally installed version of Grunt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-cli). The error message indicates this:

> either a Gruntfile wasn't found or grunt hasn't been installed locally to your project.

In other words, to run Grunt, [you need to create a `Gruntfile.js`](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started) and you must have a local copy of Grunt installed to your project alongside the file. The CLI is just there to kick off the process without troublesome fiddling.

Comment: b.c. both have the option of being installed globally.  The cli installation is obvious, grunt installation globally is what I was asking.

Comment: I added `-cli` to the first word of my answer, but in [the first link I referenced](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-cli) it explicitly says "Starting with Grunt v0.4, you should never install Grunt itself globally."

Comment: Well ... why is it an option ... I just lost 4 hours of my life.  I can't read every link on the internet.  It copied all the files ( even none that had nothing to do with grunt over to `/usr/...`  kill it.